# How do I make a JAVASCRIPT variable equal to an HTML attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am basically trying to have a number displayed that starts at 0 and goes up randomly every time you press a button. But I need a variable to equal the current number(which is stored within an h1 tag). How do I do that? Currently when I try to check if it worked by alerting the page, all I get is
[object HtmlHeadingElement] Here is my JavaScript, CSS, and HTML code, respectively:

```js
function myRandom() {
  var headnumber = document.getElementById('headnum');
  alert(headnumber)
    //the alert is just to check if '0' comes up'
}
```

```css
 

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: blue;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
button {
  margin-left: 640px;
  border: solid blue 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='headnum'>3</h1>
<button onclick="myRandom()">Button</button>
```

Comment: Do this: `var headnumber = +document.getElementById('headnum').textContent;`

Answer (score 4):

You could get the html content using innerHTML. See below,

```js
function myRandom() {
  var headnumber = document.getElementById('headnum').innerHTML;
  alert(headnumber)
    //the alert is just to check if '0' comes up'
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: blue;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
button {
  margin-left: 640px;
  border: solid blue 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='headnum'>3</h1>
<button onclick="myRandom()">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The assignment of `headnumber` is to an object returned by the `document.getElementById('headnum')` function call. In order to get the value inside the object use `document.getElementById('headnum').innerHTML`